# error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable. (xutility)

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error occurring in the 'xutility' class - It is locked as I did not create it

```
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Agent'
```

The error points to these lines in the code:

```
    // TEMPLATE FUNCTION move
template<class _InIt,
class _OutIt> inline
_OutIt _Move(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last,
    _OutIt _Dest, _Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)
{   // move [_First, _Last) to [_Dest, ...), arbitrary iterators
for (; _First != _Last; ++_Dest, ++_First)
    *_Dest = _STD move(*_First); // this line has the error
return (_Dest);
}
```

Why is this occurring? What does it mean and how can I fix it?

EDIT - this is what I grabbed from the output, can someone help me understand this? Sorry to be a complete newbie...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: D3D10DEMO, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Level.cpp
1>c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\level.cpp(449): warning     C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>  Brain.cpp
1>c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\brain.cpp(43): warning C4413: 'Brain::nodes' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the  constructor exits
1>          c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\brain.h(34) : see declaration of 'Brain::nodes'
1>c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\brain.cpp(43): warning C4413: 'Brain::roomNodeVectors' : reference member is initialized to a temporary that doesn't persist after the constructor exits
1>          c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\brain.h(35) : see declaration of 'Brain::roomNodeVectors'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2514): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Agent'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2535) : see   reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Move<_InIt,_OutIt> (_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=Agent *,
1>              _InIt=Agent *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1170) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Move<Agent*,Agent*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=Agent *,
1>              _InIt=Agent *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1165) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<Agent,std::allocator<Agent>>,
1>              _Ty=Agent
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\brain.h(41) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Agent
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2514): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'Pickup'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2535) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Move<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=Pickup *,
1>              _InIt=Pickup *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1170) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Move<Pickup*,Pickup*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=Pickup *,
1>              _InIt=Pickup *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1165) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<Pickup,std::allocator<Pickup>>,
1>              _Ty=Pickup
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\asher\documents\my dropbox\direct3d\d3d10demo_1.0\d3d10demo\brain.h(44) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Pickup
1>          ]
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You need to show *your* code which calls or results in call to the code you provided.

Comment: the line doesn't **have** the error; it _detects_ the error and the compiler _reports_ it as being detected on that line

Comment: A funny thing about templates is that error reporting is a bit messed up on them. You're trying to use a feature -- `operator=` -- that a certain class doesn't have, and the compiler can't detect this until it's looking at the gucky insides of the class. Concentrate on your _usage_ of the class, paying close attention to its documentation.

Comment: @Als I don't know where the error is occurring in my code though, it doesn't say. Is there any way to find this out? I'm not sure what i'm looking for.

Comment: Look in to the sections of code where your code might call the `_Move()` algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be calling a function template of the standard library with a type `Agent` that cannot be move-assigned to, yet the algorithm invoked needs to do just that.

As Als said in a comment to your question, you need to show the code that invokes this algorithm.

Comment: I don't know which part of the code invokes the algorithm. What should I be looking for?

Comment: @Sir: From the error message it seems you are using VC. It shows the template instantiation stack and through that you can find which line of your code caused the error.

Comment: where is the template instantiation stack? I'm not sure where to look for this. Thanks.

Comment: @SirYakalot: It's part of the full error message. You will have to look at the message in the _Output Window_, though, not in the _Error Window_. (Don't ask.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to provide the agent class.

Assuming C++11, you need to implement

```
struct Agent
{
    // .... other stuff
    Agent(Agent&& other) { /* ... */ }
    Agent& operator=(Agent&& other) { /* ... */ return *this; }
};
```

which is known as the Move Assignment operator. While you're at it, you might want to implement the move constructor as they go hand-in-hand:

```
    Agent(Agent&& other) { /* ... */ }
```

Recommended reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors
- http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/move-constructor/

and many others

Comment: "need" ? Seems it's still sufficient to implement a copy assignment operator.

Comment: @MSalters: we have neither the class nor the calling code. The functioo template shown (_Move) is not documented. You can quite clearly see that it assigns into an output iterator from `std::move`, which implies move semantics. You may be right that a copy constructor could be enough for the user.